# Windows XP occasionally hangs for 2-3 minutes as the splash screen fades in

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, freeze

This is a bit of a rare problem, I have not been able to debug or fix it or find anyone else with the issue. I hope someone here can help me out.

Once in a while, I boot up Windows XP from the first partition of the first disk (using grub, the computer dual-boots ubuntu) and it hangs as the Windows XP splash image fades in, leaving the screen with a dim image of the splash screen. After 2-3 minutes, it continues to boot as normal, no error messages or strange behavior.

I have noticed that this happens about 75% of the time when the last time the computer was shut down it was from Ubuntu, and maybe 5-10% of the time otherwise.

I have looked at system logs as far as I was able, and did not find anything the miss. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed itself after several weeks.

This is what I hate about Windows: You never know what is going to refuse to work properly until an undetermined time in the future...

Comment: This is what I love about Windows. You don't fully understand what is going on, but it ends up working anyway :]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a diagnostic more than an answer: What happens if you disable the GUI boot in MSConfig?

[image]

Comment: This is windows XP, it does not have those options (or at least I could not find them)...

I would assume that the outcome would be the same, and becuase this is an intermittent error, it is really difficult to test. My best guess at the moment is that it results from a race condition somewhere in the early boot, and it just takes a while to sort things out. I am hoping to find out what that race condition is and how to avoid it...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the No GUI boot exists in XP, but you're probably right aboutit not being all that relevant. Good luck.

Comment: In XP, it's probably the "/NOGUIBOOT" checkbox (second from top in the lower "Boot Options" frame) on the "BOOT.INI" tab.

Comment: This problem seems to have fixed itself, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, where Windows would get to a certain point during boot and take a while longer.  This was during a time of much hard drive activity (did you have HD activity?)  It turned out to be a loose SATA connector on the motherboard that reduced the drive speed by about 1/3.  After changing to another connector it never happened again.